# How to open a file by clicking on it in TreeView

Tags: winforms, treeview

How do I open a file (ex. PDF) when I click the lowest child node in my tree.

I have created a TreeView program which is automatically filled by a database file. 
[image: example]

Comment: Please add the exact problem and your code instead of an image.

Comment: @adrianoromano Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful answer. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [TreeNode Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // This is the first node in the view.
        //
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Windows");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        //
        // Another node following the first node.
        //
        treeNode = new TreeNode("Linux");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        //
        // Create two child nodes and put them in an array.
        // ... Add the third node, and specify these as its children.
        //
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("C#");
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode("VB.NET");
        TreeNode[] array = new TreeNode[] { node2, node3 };
        //
        // Final node.
        //
        treeNode = new TreeNode("Dot Net Perls", array);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
    }
```

Though example is not reading nodes from `DB`. You can do that writing a query to fetch nodes.Follow steps on following path , it will lead you from scratch

[Create a TreeView from a Database in Windows Forms and C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c5c6e2/populate-a-treeview-dynamically/)

Example Source : [Tree View](https://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview)

For opening file on Node click look at

> `public event TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler NodeMouseClick`

```
    // If a node is double-clicked, open the file indicated by the TreeNode.
    void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, 
            TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\" + e.Node.Text);//e.Node.Text contains fileName
    }
        // If the file is not found, handle the exception and inform the user.
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File not found.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Associate a path to that node, then use something like this:

```
private void LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(@".\" + "YOUR FILE NAME AND EXTENSION");
}
```

Read about: [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Starts a process resource by specifying the name of a document or application
>   file and associates the resource with a new System.Diagnostics.Process component.